# Get all except first and last n elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to get all but the first and last n elements from an array, can I do this while keeping consistent behaviour for n=0 without using an if statement? (Python 2.7).
This does what I want, but falls apart if nCut=0:

```
nCut = 3
newArray = oldArray[nCut:-nCut]
```

This is closer, but doesn't include the last element (and is also really just a slightly hidden if statement)

```
newArray = oldArray[nCut:-nCut-1*(nCut<1)]
```

I have to do this to a bunch of arrays I'm loading from files, so not having a big ugly doubled up `if` for the n=0 case would be nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `len(oldArray)` yourself instead of counting on the slicing implementation to do it for you:

```
newArray = oldArray[nCut:len(oldArray)-nCut]
```

You can also use `-nCut or None` to use `None` as the endpoint if it would otherwise be `0`:

```
newArray = oldArray[nCut:-nCut or None]
```

`None` is what a slice endpoint is set to if you don't write one in, so this is equivalent to `oldArray[nCut:]` when `nCut` is `0`. This is less immediately understandable, but also less verbose. It may be a better choice in cases of multidimensional slicing, or if the expression for the array is more complex than just `oldArray`.